# How to format code using IntelliJ format using a precommit hook?

Tags: intellij-idea, pre-commit-hook

I'm trying to configure a precommit hook to automatically format the code using IntelliJ code formatter.

Indeed, IntelliJ permit to run the formatter using the command line outside the IDE: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-formatter.html

So I've created my precommit file:

```
 git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=ACM | xargs -L 1 format
```

So to run `format` on each staged file. The problem is when I try to execute this command, the IDE shows an error message:

[image: Only one instance of IDEA can be run at a time.]

Message: Only one instance of IDEA can be run at a time.

Do you have an idea how to run `format` outside the IDE even leaving the IDE open?

Comment: Here are the instructions on how to run the command-line formatter when IDE is running. These instructions can be used with existing version without a need to upgrade:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Command-Line+Source+Code+Formatter

Answer (score 1):

You can automate the required instructions to allow running a separate instance:

```
cat >/tmp/format.properties <<EOF
idea.config.path=\${user.home}/.IntelliJIdea/format/config
idea.system.path=\${user.home}/.IntelliJIdea/format/system
EOF

git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=ACM | xargs env IDEA_PROPERTIES=/tmp/format.properties format
```

`/tmp/format.properties`: idea.properties location changes after each upgrade of IntelliJ.

In my case, I also retrieve `format.sh` location from `idea` command:

```
format_command=$(grep idea.sh $(which idea)|sed "s,idea.sh,format.sh,")
eval "env IDEA_PROPERTIES=/tmp/format.properties $format_command $(git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=ACM|xargs)"
```